# From stored procedures to REST services

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, rest, stored-procedures

I have a 6 year ago VB.NET project in Visual Studio 2005 and SQL server 2005. This project gets the data using stored procedures and I'm planning to do a mobile project but can't get the data from the database because I haven't got webservices or REST services.
How should I start to transform the stored procedures to services that can be called outside? Is there a tool that does it directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a tool to automatically do it, but here is a sample stack

Mobile App --> Asp.Net Web API --> EF / code first --> SP --> DB

Answer (score 0):

You can create a WCF web service and define wrapper methods for all your stored procedures. To retrieve data sets, you need to create data contract classes, each of which has a constructor and a set of properties (data members) representing the fields you're returning. Then you issue the Command.ExecuteReader where the command text is your sproc name. To do multiple complex operations, including inserts, updates, and deletes and combinations thereof, you just execute the stored procedures using Command.ExecuteNonQuery where the command text is again the appropriate sproc name. Your WCF web service can then be the data conduit for essentially any client: mobile, web, or WinForms. It's actually pretty easy, and you get to re-use all the logic in your stored procedures.

If your sprocs are just simple CRUD statements, then I'd suggest a REST-based WCF web service.